# Visual Studio code formatting

Tags: visual-studio, code-formatting

I've been using Visual Studio as my main IDE for a while now (I still use Emacs for some personal projects, though).

I like the way Emacs formats C/C++ code and I'd like to convince Visual Studio use similar conventions for C# code. For instance, in Emacs, a C function call looks like:

```
functionName(argument1,
             argument2,
             argument3);
```

while in the C# code formatted by Visual Studio a function call looks like:

```
functionName(argument1,
    argument2,
    argument3);
```

which seems worse to me.

Is there a way to tweak Visual Studio code formatting rules? Any plugins that can handle that?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Formatting

and

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_formatting.html#Code_Formatting

Comment: Thanks, but while that allows many customizations, I can't see a way to solve the problem in my example. It's just a minor nuissance, though.

Comment: You could also drop the first argument to the next line which would make all arguments align.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that's what I do sometimes, but it 'wastes' a line.

However I'm a bit annoyed because I consider the Emacs default formatting better (I bet I would feel the other way around if I had used Visual Studio before Emacs :-) )

Comment: One man's 'waste' is another man's clear code.  Sorry I don't have other ideas except maybe writing a VS macro for this particular bugbear.

Answer (score 7):

Resharper (above) is good.  CodeRush is now free from DevExpress.  I've enjoyed using their products over the years.

http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/

Answer (score 0):

See also this extension that will automate the process each time a file is saved : https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3ea1c920-69c4-441f-9979-ccc2752dac56